# Exercise of the form: given the random vector $(X,Y)$, find the probability density function of $X$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, solution-verification, density-function

I'm getting a wrong answer to the following exercise:

---

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector with density $$\frac{2}{y}\centerdot 1_{D}$$ where $D=\{ (x,y)\in (0,1)\times (0,\infty ) : 0<x<y,  0<xy<1\}$. Determine whether $X$ has a probability density function and if it does, find it.

---

My attempt:

Letting $x\in (0,1)$ with $x<y,y^{-1}$ we have

$$P(X\leq x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{-\infty}^{x}2y^{-1}\centerdot1_Ddt\ dy=\int_x^{1/x}\frac{x}{2y}dy=-x\ln x$$

We wish to find a function $f_X$ so that -for any $x$ with the retraints above-

$$-x\ln x=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_X(t)dt$$

which gives $$f_X(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(-x\ln x)=-1-\ln x$$

yet this is impossible since the function takes negative values for some $x\in (0,1)$. According to my teacher's notes the correct answer should be $$f_X(x)=-\ln x$$

---

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: For fixed $x$, just integrate over the $y$ region (from $y=x$ to $y=1/x$).

Comment: @zugzug I believe I did that and got $(x/2)[\ln x^{-1} - \ln x]=-x\ln x$

Comment: Yes, but you didn't integrate $f(x,y)$ over that region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The image is poor, but good enough to understand the idea. The red and blue combined is the region to integral over to calculation $P(X\leq x)$. Specifically, the mistake that you made is that if you integrate with respect to $x$ first (through dummy variable $t$), you would have to split this over two iterated integrals. The answer should be in terms of $x$. Then differentiate to get $f_X(x)$.

A far easier method is to simply integrate the joint density from $y=x$ to $y=1/x$.

Comment: You are right that integrating first with respect to $y$ yields the correct result and makes $f_X$ obvious after the first integration. Yet could you elaborate on why the integral must be broken in two when one integrates first with respect to $x$? I would understand why it needs to be broken in two if, say, we removed the condition $x<y,y^{-1}$, since then the limits of integration depend which reagion $y$ lies.