# Is it possible to determine whether a random variable has density without first finding its density function?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I was given the following exercise:

---

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector with density $$\frac{2}{y}\centerdot 1_{D}$$ where $D=\{ (x,y)\in (0,1)\times (0,\infty ) : 0<x<y,  0<xy<1\}$.

1. Determine whether $X$ and $Y$ have density.
2. Find the probability density function of $X$.

---

The only current method I know for, say,  testing whether $X$ has a density function is to -assuming it has one- compute it and then check whether the found function is in fact its density function, similarly as done in a recent [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190296/execrise-of-the-form-given-the-random-vector-x-y-find-the-probability-dens) of mine. However the way the problem is phrased seems to imply that one can determine whether $Y$ has a density function *without* having to compute it first. How can this be done?

Comment: The total probability has to be $1$.  If the description leads to a finite total, it can be normalized.  If it is infinite, there is no density.  An example of a problem - select random (rational) number between $0$ and $1$ where all have the same probability $p$.  If $p=0$, nothing is there.  If $p\gt 0$, total is infinite.